# Spark Executor Java Flight recorder- How to add executor ID in jfr filename?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, jfr

I have 2 executors running on worker nodes in spark.
I want to monitor them using java flight recorder.
For some reason I can't use jcmd to monitor executors.

Now using spark.executor.extraJavaOptions I can give static file name like record.jfr the problem is bothe executors on the worker node will write jfr detail in same file which is not ideal.
Also as name expasion is not supported in java 11 for jfr file name (https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8269127) I can't use %p option.

I was wondering if Spark provides place holders for executor id that it can replace when it creates executors? that way I can pass filename as say-> {{EXECUTOR_ID}}_record.jfr and will get separate recording for each executor.

The spark documentation for spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions at (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) mentions that it provides place holder for Executor ID and Application ID but not sure what place holder is.

I tried -recording.jfr and {{EXECUTOR_ID}.jfr (suggested here [Spark Executor Id in JAVA_OPTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534414/spark-executor-id-in-java-opts)) but it produces file named -recording.jfr and {{EXECUTOR_ID}.jfr respectively.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but you can specify a directory, for example -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=/some/directory , and then JFR will generate a filename from the PID and timestamp, for example hotspot-pid-92441-id-1-2024_01_08_19_34_50.jfr. You may not be able to correlate the spark instances, but they will get different filenames.

Comment: That would also have worked for me, as I can find process I’d of the executor I want to monitor as far as jfr file is separate for each executor. But it didn’t work for me the options I used is- -XX:StartFlightRecording=delay=10s,duration=30m,filename=/my/dir/

Comment: The directory must exist and the JVM process must have read and write privileges for it to work. That said, there seems to be a bug when duration=<time> is used in combination with filename=<directory> and the recording ends before the JVM exits. I filed a bug https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8323425